# numpy histogram2d return zeros where there is data

Tags: python, numpy, histogram

I am having trouble with numpy's histogram2d. I have the following code:

```
hist, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(rad_dist, tot_L, bins=1000, weights=None)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(40, 10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(131)
plt.imshow(np.log10(hist), interpolation='bilinear', origin='low',extent=
[xedges[0], xedges[-1], yedges[0], yedges[-1]], aspect='auto')
plt.colorbar()
```

where `rad_dist`,`tot_L` are 1d arrays with the same length. The range of values is 0 to 97, -0.015 to 0.015 respectively.

The plot produced by the code is[image: Plot of histogram]
and I know for sure I have substantial amount of data with values in all ranges. For some reason, everything is concentrated on this middle line

EDIT:
This is the scatter plot of the data:

[image: scatter plot]

Comment: Would you be able to attach a picture of the output of `plt.scatter(rad_dist, tot_L)` to see the data distribution?

Comment: @TillHoffmann Just added

Comment: It looks like the problem is with your data rather than the histogram: the scatter plot shows the same distribution concentrated on a line close to `tot_L` being zero. Note that you need to transpose the numpy histogram when you use `imshow`.